# cannot run on '<default>' when using clion to debugging jvm 12 source code

Tags: c, clion

I am tried to debugging the JDK 12 JVM source code in CLion, now all the compile work success. I have runned this command:

```
bash configure --with-boot-jdk='/Users/dolphin/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.10.hs-adpt' --with-debug-level=slowdebug --with-target-bits=64 --disable-warnings-as-errors --enable-dtrace --with-jvm-variants=server


make CONF=macosx-x86_64-server-slowdebug compile-commands


make CONF=macosx-x86_64-server-slowdebug
```

but when I started the debugging, the CLion shows error like this:

[image]

this is the CLion JVM debug config:

[image]

this is the build target config:

[image]

am I missing something? what should I do to fix this probem? I am using MacBook Pro with Intel Chip, the OS is `macOS Monerey 13.2.1`, the CLion version is: `CLion 2021.3.4`.

this is the CLion debugging config:

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should not add a `CMake Application`, tried to add `Custom Build Application` in CLion to seem if works.